# cannot link with glew32 for "glewInit()"

Tags: linker, glew

```
#include <gl/glew.h>

int main()
{
    glewInit();
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    return true;
}
```

I've already set up header search path, library search path, glew32.lib & opengl32.lib. However Visual Studio 2012 cannot link with

> error LNK2019: _*imp*_glewInit

The **strangest** thing is that I can link *glActiveTexturet* ( or *__glewActiveTexture* ), but I cannot link *glewInit*

Answer (score 0):

OK finally I got it...I use **glew** from **cuda**, which absolutely has some problems... I overwrite glew.h & glew32.lib from sourceforge, which works now...